# Is there a list of Microsoft Windows 10 localized edition names?

Tags: windows-10, localization

Is there a list of all of the possible localized names of the Microsoft Windows 10 operating system editions?

For example, this is an example that a French user showed me:

OLD: `Microsoft WindowsÂ 10 Entreprise`

Update: `Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise` (ignore the Â, that's separate problem)

Notice: The spelling of the word "enterprise" is French, not English.

What other variations are possible? Surely there must be a complete list somewhere?

Comment: You might find something on the [Search and Download International Terminology - Microsoft | Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language)

Comment: Looks like output from a  poor automated translator rather than official naming: And the _Letter A With Circumflex_  comes from mojibake. UTF-8 codes for `©` or for `®` are `0xC2A9` (`Â©`)  _Copyright Sign_ and `0xC2AE`  (`Â®`)  _Registered Sign_, respectively.

Comment: @JosefZ, you're right. I just discovered that the system sending this information to me is accidentally inserting a hidden UTF-8 character. The "entreprise" word is legit French spelling of Enterprise, so my question overall still remains.